# Do not repeat ListIterator element if next() and previous() used subsequently

Tags: java, listiterator

When you use next() and then previous() right after ListIterator will return the same element of a list, how can I make it so if I use one after another it will skip the current element and go to the next one? I'm trying to use two buttons to scroll back and forth between a list of months and with my current code if I press next and I want to go back, I will need to press back twice.

```
Label monthLabel = new Label(month);
    intoHbox.setConstraints(monthLabel, 1, 0);
    intoHbox.setConstraints(prevMonth, 0, 0);


    LinkedList<String> year = new LinkedList();
    year.add("January");
    year.add("February");
    year.add("March");
    year.add("April");
    year.add("May");
    year.add("June");
    year.add("July");
    year.add("August");
    year.add("September");
    year.add("October");
    year.add("November");
    year.add("December");


//make the current month the starting position
    int position = 0;
    for (String monthNow : year){
        if(monthNow.contains(month)){
            break;
        }
        else{
            position++;
        }
    }


    ListIterator<String> it = year.listIterator();
    it = year.listIterator(position + 1);
    positionInList = it;
    nextMonth.setOnAction(e -> {

        if (positionInList.hasNext()){
        String currentLabel = positionInList.next();
            monthLabel.setText(currentLabel);


        }
        else{
            positionInList = year.listIterator(0);

            monthLabel.setText(positionInList.next());
        }


    });


    prevMonth.setOnAction(e -> {

        if (positionInList.hasPrevious()){

            monthLabel.setText(positionInList.previous());

        }
        else{
            positionInList = year.listIterator(12);
            monthLabel.setText(positionInList.previous());
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be simpler to store the current position in a variable and use it directly.

Create a small utility class, which will also help with the fact that you can't modify an int within a lambda if it's not final. You can make it private and include it directly in your main class.

```
private static class Position {
  private final List<String> year;
  private int position;

  Position(List<String> year, String current) {
    this.year = year;
    this.position = year.indexOf(current);
    if (this.position == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid month: " + current);
  }

  String next() {
    ++position;
    if (position >= year.size()) position = 0;
    return year.get(position);
  }
  String previous() {
    --position;
    if (position < 0) position = year.size() - 1;
    return year.get(position);
  }
}
```

Then in your method, you can use:

```
Position position = new Position(year, month);

nextMonth.setOnAction(e -> monthLabel.setText(position.next());
prevMonth.setOnAction(e -> monthLabel.setText(position.previous());
```

Also note that it would be a little more efficient to use an `ArrayList` in that case because it supports random access in O(1) - although the difference will be small for such a small list.